# Data transfer to Android USB Digital Audio device

Tags: usb, audio, android

Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above supports a subset of USB audio class 1 (UAC1) features:
https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb.html

related links:
https://source.android.com/accessories/custom.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Can a USB audio class 1 device interface with an associated Android application via AOA?

It seems that Android can handle only one accessory at a time, so I can't present a USB audio and an AOA custom accessory on the bus separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a USB audio class 1 device interface with an associated Android application via AOA?

No. The UAC1 is a Host implementation, the Android device acts as a OTG Host to a usb audio device. The AOA is a slave implementation, that is the Android device acts like a slave to the AOA device which is the host. Most android devices (if not all) will not be capable of acting as both on the same bus. Some android devices have multiple usb ports, including one for OTG Host and another for Slave.